# Ambiguity at Builder Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, builder

I have several questions on the Builder Pattern.
Builder Pattern uses several methods for constructing an instance of a class and each method return `this` as return value.

My questions are:

1. Why does each method return a return type instance of same class?
2. What is the benefit of this pattern vs using setter method?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the builder pattern without having the methods return `this`. But the advantage of having the methods return an instance of the same class is that you can chain the methods together. For example:

```
return new ObjectBuilder().withWidget("A").withGadget(5).build();
```

The primary reason to use the pattern (over setters on a constructed object) is to separate the logic for building an object from the object itself. Typically this means that the built object has no public setters which simplifies it considerably. However it might need either very complex constructors or protected setters to support the builder.

Comment: This means because for code style? I think exist stronger reasons.

Comment: You can implement builders with void methods. Returning a reference to the builder is convenience only.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why does each method return a return type instance of same class?

This is not strictly necessary. You could return something else (or void). Returning the `Builder` makes it a *fluent* builder, meaning that you can chain method calls conveniently, perhaps avoiding the need for an explicit reference to the builder:

```
Built thing = new Built.Builder().setFoo("bar").build();
```

Vs

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
builder.setFoo("bar");
Built built = builder.build();
```

Note that each chained call pushes another call onto the stack, so you are limited in the number of chained calls that you can make - although you are practically unlikely to hit this issue.

Also, making the `Builder` fluent does create more boilerplate code - having to `return this` at the end of every method would be annoying to do manually if you were creating a large number of setter methods.

> 2. What is the benefit of this pattern vs using setter method?

One benefit is the potential for immutability of the built object, and all of the desirable properties that provides (safe sharing of the instance with untrusted clients, no need for cloning, thread safety etc).

For example:

```
final class Built {
  private final String foo;

  private Built(Builder builder) {
    this.foo = builder.foo;
  }

  String getFoo() { return foo; }

  static final class Builder {
    private String foo;

    Built build() { return new Built(this); }
    Builder setFoo(String value) { this.foo = value; return this; }
  }
}
```

Instances of `Built` are immutable because there is no mutable state and inheritance is forbidden. This means that if I give you an instance of `Built` (or you give me an instance), then I know that you can't do something to change it subsequently - it is not necessary to reason about state changes.

Comment: i am not convinced,sorry :( I believe setter methods do same work also. For second question,please a sample for immutability support by this pattern?

Comment: Returning `this` from a method is not limited to `Builder` classes - after all, a `Builder` class is just a "regular" class with a particular intended purpose. So there is no difference between a setter on a `Builder` and a setter on any other class.

Comment: Re: immutability - I've added an example, but I'd recommend reading Effective Java 2nd Ed Item 15 ("Minimize mutability").

Answer (score 1):

Builder pattern similare to Factory Pattern but use for complex construction. This means you set a factory interface an related implementation but in builder pattern this Structure use for complex construction.